# How do I solve this dynamic programming problem?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, dynamic-programming

I am using the C++ language.

Mark has 'N' days. Initially he is at position (h1,0) on the X-axis. On each day he can go to the co-ordinates (h1+a,0) or (h1+b,0) or (h1+c,0) . He can select any one of the choice he wants. Each day he can go to (+a , +b or +c).
At the N-th day, he has to reach the position (h2,0).
Count the number of ways in which Mark can reach (h2,0) in N days.

Values of N,h1,h2,a,b,c are large(co-ordinates and values of a,b,c can be negative as well, in some cases a=b or b=c or c=a or a=b=c)

My approach is:- At each day, I store the positions which he can reach on that particular day with the count(number of ways) to reach that position. I am using a map to do this. And this approach is not efficient.

Can somebody share a much more efficient approach ?

My second approach which must work is the variation of coin-exchange-problem :-)

Example:-

N=3,h1=0,h2=6,a=1,b=2,c=3

Answer : -7(number of ways)

1st way:-(1+2+3)

2nd way:-(1+3+2)

3rd way:-(2+1+3)

4th way:-(2+3+1)

5th way:-(3+1+2)

6th way:-(3+2+1)

7th way:-(2+2+2)

Format:-(Choice on 1st day+Choice on 2nd day+Choice on 3rd day)

Constraints:- 
1<=N<=10^5 .

-10^9<=h1,h2,a,b,c<=10^9 .

Comment: How large N can be?

Comment: @mahbubcseju I've added the constraints :-)

Comment: The 7th way should be 2+2+2. Coin change seems to be very similar indeed. You can calculate all the unique ways to reach h2 and then in the end calculate the permutations with N! / (product of factorial of occurence for each number) for each one of them. E.g. 1+1+4+7+7+7 would be 6! / (2! * 3!), the 2! comes from the two 1s and the 3! from the three 7s .On second thought this probably doesn't work because 10^5! is incredibly large.

Comment: Don't you have to give the number of possibilities modulo something? The number of possibilities just seems way too big.

Comment: Yup, it has to be modulo 10^9+7, I did not mention it!!

Comment: I wonder if a study of Diophantine equations might help since `ax + by + cz = h2 - h1; x + y + z = N`

Comment: to be exact this is the uniques way to reach the point `[(1,1,1,1,1,1),(1,1,1,1,2),(1,1,1,3),(1,2,3),(2,2,2),(2,2,1,1),(3,3)]` Op defined ways are wrong

Comment: @prashantrana you are wrong . You've misunderstood the question. Read it again. Each day you can make only 1 move. So for 3 days only 3 number of moves are allowed.

Comment: @גלעדברקן That just might not work cuz when x=y=z=1, (1,1,1) is counted as only 1 dolution whereas in my example, they are counted as 6 different solutions :-)

Comment: @Guhfggehlthon sorry on my part , i hadn't saw the restriction of no of days, then in the list one to to find length equal to n and find combination of that

Comment: @גלעדברקן    This problem has been solved by your idea! Congratzz!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know how much times a,b,c used then you can easily say the result.

For example, if we use x times of a, y times of b and z times of c to get h2 from h1 we can say that way of using  x times of a, y times of b and z times of c is

> factorial(x+y+z)/(factorial(x)*factorial(y)*factorial(z))

.

Now how can we know the values of x,y,z . There can be a lot of triplet of x,y,z.

Now , we can consider 0 to n every number  as x.

So for each x from 0 to n,

> x*a+y*b+z*c=(h2-h1)
>   y+z=n-x

As we know the values of x,a,b,c,h2,h1
  we can rewrite the equation,

> y*b+z*c=(h2-h1-x*a)
>
>     y*b+z*c=k, where  k= (h2-h1-x*a)

Now solve the problem for the following equations:

> y*b+z*c=k
>    y+z=n-x

So there can be solution or not for that equation such that y and z is an integer.

If there is a solution then these equation will be solvable.

After finding y and z,  we can calculate the permutation  for x by using

> factorial(x+y+z)/(factorial(x)*factorial(y)*factorial(z))

.

So if there is no any solution, then you should skip current x.
By this way calculate y and z for each x from 0 to n and sum them.

Comment: You will then have to count the number of ways, i.e. permutations of xh1, yh2 and zh3...

Comment: If a is used x times, b is used y times and  c is used z times permutation will be x*y*z. Is not it?

Comment: Certainly not! Suppose you'll have to use h1, h2 and h3 one time each, then you have 6 possibilities not 1, isn't it ? h1h2h3, h1h3h2, h2h1h3, h2h3h1, h3h1h2 h3h2h1...

Comment: factorial(x+y+z)/(factorial(x)*factorial(y)*factorial(z)) ??

Comment: Sorry ! I forgot the normal permutation rules :(

Comment: Happens :-)  :-)

Comment: @Guhfggehlthon I did not get your comment. Will you please elaborate it ?

Comment: @mahbubcseju There is a problem in your solution, for each 'x' , the possible values of 'y' and 'z' can be too many and that will explode the time limits. And x can be zero as well. You may edit it.

Comment: y and z can be so many thats true but you have to find the one such that y+z=(n-x).

Comment: Let n=100 and i=34 , now, y+z=66 , now there are many pairs (y,z) such that y+z=66....which will you select ? Got the loophole?

Comment: But from extended euclid, you will get some solution(y,z) in which for only one y+z will be   (n-i)  if b and c are not equal.

Comment: Yes! if b and c are equal then we dont need any extended euclid .Easier then

Comment: @ suppose a!=b!=c ...... Now x=2,y=4,z=1.....we got the answer for this....but you algorithm ignored x=2,y=3,z=2..... (y+z=5) in both the cases, then how will the final answer be correct if you only select one (y,z) for each 'x' . Please explain in detail with example....and some code of euclid if possible.. to explain the working:-)

Comment: After finding  one y and z ,we have to either add something to y and minus something to z or minus something to y and add something to z  to get others (y,z). So it will form a maxima like triangle . So there will be at most two solution which will obey the two rules (by+cz=k && y+z=(n-x)).

Comment: I encourage you to explain that with an example that only 2 pairs of (y,z) are possible for each  'x' . So things get clear for everyone . You may add it in your answer. :-)

Comment: My explanation :- There are 2 equations only:- y+z=k1 and y*b+z*c=k2 ; we know all the values of k1,k2,b,c...After solving the simultaneous equations we will only get one value of  of (y and z) :-)

Comment: :P Then we also dont need the extended euclid too .Just solving two equation solve the problem :P Missed a great thing :P

Comment: Yup, we both(especially me) created so much fuss and finally reached such a simple baby solution :p Thanks a lot btw :-)

Comment: Welcome ! Thanks a lot too !

Comment: @mahbubcseju You are an experienced programmer. Can you share your ideas on this algorithmic problem:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56781161/how-to-solve-multiple-queries-efficiently  .

Comment: @Guhfggehlthon I answered in your question thread and in another question thread too. Unfortunately yours one is deleted by moderator. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56782467/8695011

Comment: @mahbubcseju Any ideas on this graph problem : - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61082584/maximum-matching-for-line-graphs