# Get the element for which the absolute difference between left half product and right half product is minimum

Tags: python, c++, algorithm

I want to find the element in a given array (n elements) such that the absolute difference between the left half product and the right half product is minimum

```
(abs(arr[0]*arr[1]*...arr[x]-arr[x+1]*arr[x+2]...arr[n]))
```

the question also updates the values of the array regularly 'm' times. I want to get answers of all queries in O(m log n).

I have tried an approach which takes O(n*m) time and it is not working due to TLE error.

Comment: There are already a lot of posts here on this specific problem. In facy tou can make it *O(n)*.

Comment: i want to do it in O(log n) not O(n)

Comment: what is *m* here? Furthermore I mean *O(n)* to find the minimum, not *log(n)* for a single query.

Comment: m is the number of queries and n is number of array elements, a query can update array element by arr[i]*=val and another type of query needs to print the index where minimum abs diff occurs

Comment: When are these m update queries being done? Every time after you return the minimum abs difference index?

Comment: @JuanCarlosRamirez Can you show me other posts on this same question ?

Answer (score 1):

**The only approach comes in my mind:**

Multiplication of such a big number is hard.

we can covert this as

> log10(A[1]*A[2]*...*A[x])- log10(A[x+1]*A[x+2]*..*A[n])
>   log10(A[1])+log10(A[2])+..+log10(A[x])-log10(A[x+1])+log10(A[x+2])+..+log10(A[n])

Now these result are storable in double.

As abs((A[1]*A[2]*...*A[x])- (A[x+1]*A[x+2]*..*A[n])) should be minimized,
  this equation will follow the rules of ternary search.

So in each iternation of ternary search we need the result of

> log(A[1])+log(A[2])+..+log(A[x])
>       and
>        log(A[x+1])+log(A[x+2])+..+log(A[n])

As  there is some update, we need a data structure for finding them with lower 
complexity like segment tree.

So overall complexity will be log(n)*log(n)  for each query.

Comment: Your solution is good, but the value of elements in the array is too big, if we take log of it, we'll have to deal with precision problem of 18 digits, even while comparing, it will take a toll on us :

Comment: example...log10(29867969678)= 10.475205701760142 , but in C++, it gives....log10(29867969678)= 10.4752  ...It means all our calculations of ternary search will go wrong :(

Comment: Then you can try by using log10^9()

Comment: What is log 10^9() may I ask ? I typed it in the gcc. compiler and it showed error :p

Comment: I don't have any idea too :(

Comment: I am searching extensively on the internet on how to deal with log precision stuff....as soon as I GET IT. I'll  tell you and then you can update your answer.

Comment: can you tell me how can I do binary search/ternary search to get 'x' in log(n)  time ? You may assume I've all the prefix and suffix sums precomputed :-)

Comment: Binary search will not work here . Use ternary search on x only! In ternary search you will have two key index mid1 and mid2 . Based on the result of mid1 and mid2 find the most feasible one.

Comment: @mahbubsceju Sadly, I've realized that ternary search will not work as our array is not sorted...even though th prefix array is always sorted...ternary search simply does not work as the absolute difference can be anything for every indice....say our array is :-  1 1 1 2 3 1 ......For x=0; y=absolute-difference=7, for x=1, y=5, for x=2,y=4,....for x=3,y=1....for x=4,y=7....so y={7,5,4,1,7} .... so you can see that y increases at few places...and decrease at other places, it is independent of the indices, so ternary search won't be fruitful :(

Comment: Contradicting my own words, I've reached a simple solution which uses binary search :-)

Comment: I don't see how either ternary or binary search, or a segment tree are helpful here. Could you please explain the full algorithm? (No need for code, just a specific description of how the update and finding the requested minimum would be achieved.) (cc @Guhfggehlthon)

Comment: After taking log, all you gotta do is find 2-subarrays with min. Absolute difference. That is:- (a(i)+...a(x))-((a(x+1)+....a(n)) .

Comment: So on the prefix array, just do binary search for x/2, where x=sum of prefix array :-)

Comment: @Guhfggehlthon we can only binary search on sorted arrays. The prefix sum array is not guaranteed to be sorted if elements can be negative.

Comment: @mahbubcseju Can you desrive the solution to this problem:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56908323/how-can-i-solve-this-dynamic-programming-problem